# Какую базу данных использовать для Android приложения?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, react-native, firebase-database

Начали делать приложение на подобие блаблакар по функционалу. Возник вопрос, какую использовать базу данных?!

Есть вариант firebase, но там есть ограничения по пользователям. Есть предложение использовать firestore, но и там есть ограничения. Далее в очереди SQlite, но подойдет ли это для такого приложения?!

Comment: SQLite точно не подойдёт, т.к. это локальная БД, то есть она постоянно должна находиться на одном устройстве с приложением.

Comment: Ничего нет бесплатного. Нужно без ограничений и сторонних сервисов? Тогда используйте свой сервер, делайте на нем БД и обращайтесь через API.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы можете использовать свой сервер, а на нем развернуть API, через которое и будете обращаться к своей БД. 
Например это можно реализовать на python используя Django + Django REST framework. Django из коробки имеет возможность работы с SQLite. В дальнейшем его же можно использовать и для веб версии вашего сервиса, если такая планируется.

Comment: Можно ли это сделать,если работаем на react native или flutter?